# Need an SQL script to update a new column with the values concatenated from 3 columns of the same table

Tags: sql, db2

I need a prepare an SQL script to be given to my production support team to run this in production. We have created a new column in the DB2 table. This column should be filled with the data by concatenating 3 column values of the same table in the same row.

To give a history, all the reason text which are entered in the front end are inserted into the request table by unstringing into 3 columns. Since they had limited length, we created a new column with increased length and going forward all insert will go into the new column. But we need to move all the existing data in the old 3 columns to his new one. S this SQL update is just an one time exercise.

Table: tab_request

[image]

We added new column to have a increased character length and to align with other table nomenclature. Now I need the script to update the column reasontext as below

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have such a column with automatically generated by db2 content? I mean if `reason1`, for example, is updated, then `reasontext` is updated automatically. You are not able to change the `reasontext` column manually in this case.

Comment: Nope I dont want that trigger to happen. Actually we are going to stop insert data into those 3 columns and instead the value from front end will be inserted into the new column alone. This script is an one time update to move the existing data from the 3 columns to the new column.

Answer (score 0):

`update` `set field1 || ....` should be your dml script. use `coalesce()` function to convert those `null` values to `''`.

```
Update table1
set reasontext = 
    (coalesce(reason_1, '') || ' ' || coalesce(reason_2,'') || ' ' || coalesce(reason_3,''))
```

Comment: I am getting SQLCODE = -170, ERROR:  THE NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS SPECIFIED FOR CONCAT IS INVALID

Comment: This worked. I added RTRIM as well and it worked like charm

Comment: @MohanrajKanagaraj, actually, standard coalesce() should support multiple parameters, not sure why db2 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

update tab_request set reasontext=CONCAT(reason_1,' ',reason_2,' ',reason_3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid unnecessary spaces -- in the event that some reasons are `NULL` -- then you can use `trim()` with `coalesce()`:

```
update table1
    set reasontext = trim(coalesce(' ' || reason_1, '') ||
                          coalesce(' ' || reason_2, '') ||
                          coalesce(' ' || reason_3, '') 
                         );
```

This is equivalent to `concat_ws()` available in some databases.